# Why aren't WHERE and ORDER BY compatible?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

Whenever I try using `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` in the same MySQL query (either in php or c#), it doesn't work. I've always managed to find another way to do this, but I'm wondering why we can't use both of them at once.. Thanks.

EDIT: Seems to work now, but I swear to god it never worked for me before, EVER! No matter of the order they're placed in.. :s Thank you guys anyway! :)

Comment: I'm confused...what are you talking about? Examples?

Comment: They are supposed to be compatible. Define "it doesn't work". Provide a simple, short, complete example of how you can reproduce an apparent incompatibility. Your question is running on a perilous assumption and you aren't likely to get much help if you can't elaborate.

Comment: They *are* compatible. The problem is elsewhere. How about showing us the query you are trying so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use them both, you have to place them in the correct order.

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.field
ORDER BY t.field1
```

I would suggest reading up on it.

[WHERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html)

[ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely use them both at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use them both within the same statement.  You need to make sure that they are in the correct order:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table
 WHERE Column = Something
 ORDER
    BY ColumnId
```

Answer (score 2):

They are very compatible. I suspect *the syntax used is wrong*. To get suggestions on *how to write it correctly, include the "wrong" syntax in the post*.

This is valid SQL (assuming such a schema exists):

```
SELECT age
FROM users
WHERE age > 42
ORDER BY age ASC
```

Note that `ORDER BY` has to come at the end.

Please see the [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) for the particular database (there are deviations between vendor and version). Note that C# LINQ is "similar to" SQL, *but is not* SQL.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

PEBKAC: this is not an issue with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

They are supposed to be compatible...

The only thing I can think of offhand is this: Are you using `WHERE` before `ORDER BY`? In some RDBMS implementations, the order of the parts of the query is very important.